# VSIX - Get RootSuffix in Visual STudio extension

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

To debug Visual Studio extensions you can start an experimental instance with a certain "RootSuffix". See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/the-experimental-instance?view=vs-2022.

Is there a way to know the provided rootsuffix in the code of your extension?

I.e. "Exp" if the instance was started with "devenv.exe /RootSuffix Exp"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be retrieved with following code:

```
IVsAppCommandLine cmdline = (IVsAppCommandLine)GetService(typeof(SVsAppCommandLine));
cmdline.GetOption("rootSuffix", out var present, out var value)
```

Answer (score 1):

The DTE object has a [CommandLineArguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte._dte.commandlinearguments?view=visualstudiosdk-2019) property which contains the information you need.